# Mongock (Mongobee) and Spring Boot in unit test

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongobee, mongock

I have the following dummy class:

```
@Document("items")
static class Item {
    int i;

    public Item() {
    }

    public Item(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int getI() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

And here's a simple `@Changeset`:

```
//@Autowired
@ChangeSet(order = "001", id = "add_items", author = "tester")
public void changeset1(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_DB_ITEMS; i++) {
        mongoTemplate.insert(new Item(i));
    }
}
```

After `@Changeset` is called, the unit test is running (Notice that mongoTemplate is `@Autowired`)

```
@Test
public void test() {
    List<Item> items = mongoTemplate.findAll(Item.class);
    System.out.println(items);
}
```

Problem: I'm getting zero items from `findAll()`

I found that when I'm adding `@Autowired` to `changeset1()` it does work (commented above) - I'm getting all items.

Can you explain why? In the [examples](https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock#defining-changeset-methods), I don't see they need to `@Autowired`

Should I even do that? I mean, can it damage the locking mechanism of Mongock?

Comment: can you provide more information, like the way Mongock is configured.

Also, are you sure your changeLog is getting executed? It maybe the due to Mongock not finding the changelog and never executed.

Do you have any error in the log?

Answer (score 2):

Without your complete code, it's hard to figure out what went wrong. Most likely spring configuration isn't configured correctly, so without autowire annotation, mongoTemplate isn't instantiated properly in Spring container. If you care to track deeper into the MongoTemplate source code and comparing the execution path before the annotation change and after it, you will find out why.

I would suggest following their example to find out anything missing in your project. https://github.com/cloudyrock/mongock-samples/tree/master/samples-mongock-spring/sample-mongock-spring-v2

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and in my case the bean creator/runner had a **mispelled package name** for the builder atribute **"changeLogScanPackage"**

```
@Bean
public SpringMongock springMongock(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate, Environment springEnvironment) {
  return new SpringMongockBuilder(mongoTemplate, "changeLogScanPackage")
        .setSpringEnvironment(springEnvironment)
      .setLockQuickConfig() OR .setLockConfig(3, 4, 3) 
       ...other setters
      .build();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but per Mongock [documentation](https://www.mongock.io/spring-profiles), you need to use `MongockTemplate`, not `MongoTemplate`

Comment: That's correct. However, from version5 this has been improved and you can(and should use MongoTemplate), but you can use MongockTemplate too.